# XSL fo Create a Table Dynamically

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I need to create a table in by calling a template in XSL:FO
For e.g.
I was hoping to call a template function

**Table Template**

```
<xsl:template name="getTable">
```

Create table by using the fo:table tags and call the column template and pass a parameter for no of columns

Create the fo:body tag and  call the row template and pass the no of row  as parameter

```
 </xsl:template>
```

**Column template** e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="getcolumn">
</xsl:template>
Row template
```

Call the Cell template  and pass the no of Cells parameter

```
 </xsl:template>
```

**Cell template**

```
<xsl:template name="getCell">
```

call the  another template

```
</xsl:template>
```

I have got as far creating a table in XSL:FO. I can create the table in XSL:fo by a table below but I am looking to create a table as I need to replicate it many times depending upon the input.

```
    <fo:table  xsl:use-attribute-sets="Table" >
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-column />
                                <fo:table-body>
                                  <fo:table-row >
                                    <fo:table-cell  >


                                      <fo:block  xsl:use-attribute-sets="JobTaskHeaderBackground">

                                       School1
                                      </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block>
<xsl:call-template name="Required">
                                      <xsl:with-param name="ElementToCheck" select='m:SchoolName' />
</xsl:call-template>
                                    </fo:block>
                                 </fo:table-cell>
                              </fo:table-row>
                              </fo:table-body>
                              </fo:table>
```

Comment: It's still not clear how you intend to populate the multiple tables - assuming you don't want them to have identical data.

Comment: Your `xsl:with-param` aren't allowed at those points in XSLT.

Comment: Tony you are right that was typo I have enclosed it inside the call-template tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to replicate it many times depending upon the parameter
>   e.g.(NoOfTables)param=2

You can have the template call itself recursively, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template name="generate-tables">
    <xsl:param name="number-of-tables"/>
    <xsl:param name="number-of-rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="number-of-columns"/>

    <xsl:if test="$number-of-tables > 1">

    <!-- code to generate a table -->

    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:call-template name="generate-tables">
        <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
            <xsl:with-param name="number-of-tables" select="$number-of-tables - 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="number-of-rows" select="$number-of-rows"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="number-of-columns" select="$number-of-columns"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you want all the generated tables to have the same number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the reply, but how do I pass a parameter to dynamically get the 'm:SchoolName'  value (inside the cell template). The School name is obtained from another template **Required**.

Comment: @user1339913 I am afraid I have no idea what this refers to. You need to edit your question and provide a [mcve].